# SSMS sorting result grid columns

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SSMS (v18) when viewing the result grid (by right clicking on a table and selecting Edit top X rows), is there a way to sort the columns alphabetically?

We have a table with many columns and navigating to the right one is a huge effort.

Comment: No, not out of the box, it provides the columns by their ordinal position. You could, if you wanted, write your own extension for the application if you wanted though.

Comment: you can write your own select and edit from it, the select can select whatever columns you want

Comment: If you have columns `A, B, C, ... X, Y, Z` and you want Z to show first in the results table, do `SELECT Z, * FROM TABLE`

Comment: Don't use the Edit top X grid. It has many issues. Just write an update statement for the data you want to change. Once you get comfortable with it you will find it is much faster and easier anyway.

Comment: Is there any performance or other benefit to the order of the fields in the table? Meaning can I just change the ordinal order of the fields once to be in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will create a view for a specific table, but return all columns in alphabetical order. You can edit that later. Or you can keep just the select statement. Hope it helps

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(128) = 'yourTableName'
DECLARE @schemaName NVARCHAR(128) = 'yourSchemaName'
DECLARE @databaseName NVARCHAR(128) = 'yourDatabaseName'
DECLARE @viewName NVARCHAR(128) = 'yourViewName'
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @query += QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ', '
FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName
    AND TABLE_NAME = @tableName 
    AND TABLE_CATALOG = @databaseName
    ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
) AS T

-- Remove the last comma and space
SET @query = LEFT(@query, LEN(@query)-1) 

-- Create the dynamic SQL to create the view
SET @query = N'CREATE VIEW ' + QUOTENAME(@databaseName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@viewName) + 
' AS SELECT ' + @query + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@databaseName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)

-- Execute the dynamic SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```